# in pandas dataframe, use grouping to find how many items with certain value belong to each manufacturer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Just learning pandas, so any help would be great. I have a dataframe with columns of names of cereals, manufacturers and their rating. I want to figure out how many of the cereals have a rating higher than 50 and determine how many that have achieved this rating belong to each manufacturer

This is what I tried:

```
df_3['HighRate'] = 'No' 
df_3['HighRate'][df['rating'] > 50 = 'Yes' 
dfGrouped2 = df_3.groupby(['manufacturer','HighRate'])

 dfGrouped2
```

and

```
HighRate = df_3[df_3[['rating'] > 50]
dfGrouped2 = df_3.groupby(['manufacturer','HighRate'])
dfGrouped2




name    manufacturer    rating
Cheerios    G           50.764999
Wheaties    C           51.592193
```

Comment: If you can share a sample of your DataFrame it will help in providing a solution.

Comment: I added a couple lines

Comment: You may also want to play around with a [multi'index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) , using mfg and rating for the levels, and see if it has any advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
df_high = df[df['rating'] > 50]
df_high.groupby('manufacturer')['manufacturer'].agg(['count'])
```

This will give the count of manufacturers whose have cereals rating higher than 50.